# Can't type into any HTML input field anywhere in my project

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I am making an ASP.NET project and I am building the login page. However, I cannot type into any kind of input field no matter what I try.
My Steps:

-I set the z-index to an absurdly large number with the '!important' tag after.
-I have changed the color of the text to make sure it wasn't white.
-I tried to make an editable span tag, and all I can do is use the delete button to erase forward.
-Backspace and any kind of typing does not work.

I have tried to use the ASP Text Box, and I have created input fields on other pages and other parts of this page.I am totally stumped.

Console logging to see if the text is invisible gives no results. All that happens is you can click into a field, and the cursor flashes as if you are typing nothing into it.

Would the be a project configuration or setting that could cause this issue?

```html
<div class="login-page" style="color:black;">
  <div class="form">

    <form>
      <lottie-player src="https://assets4.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/XRVoUu3IX4sGWtiC3MPpFnJvZNq7lVWDCa8LSqgS/profile.json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="justify-content: center;" loop autoplay></lottie-player>

      <input style="z-index:10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000!important;" id="uname" type="email" placeholder="&#xf007;  username" />
      <input style="z-index: 1000!important;" type="password" id="password" placeholder="&#xf023;  password" />
      <i class="fas fa-eye" onclick="show()"></i>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button onclick="show()">LOGIN</button>
      <p class="message"></p>
    </form>

    <form class="login-form">
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='https://buy.stripe.com/test_7sI4i2b7P5qY8Vy4gg'">SIGN UP</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Using chrome, but I also tried debugging on Edger to see if it was a Chrome-only issue, same problem. Something must just be broken about my project setup, I'm switching from ASP.NET to React for the time being.

Comment: I use Safari and it looks normal to me

Comment: You have 2 form tags in that markup - a webforms page ONLY allows having one form tag in that page.

Comment: BTW: that massive `z-index` value is useless and may cause it to be ignored/fail. Max value is `2^31  - 1 = 2,147,483,647`